# Can I use variables for selectors?

Tags: css, variables, sass, css-selectors

I have this variable:

```
$gutter: 10;
```

I want to use it in a selector like so SCSS:

```
.grid+$gutter {
    background: red;
}
```

so the output becomes CSS:

```
.grid10 {
    background: red;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
$gutter: 10;

.grid#{$gutter} {
    background: red;
}
```

If used in a string for example in a url:

```
background: url('/ui/all/fonts/#{$filename}.woff')
```

Comment: I have a similar question also involving using variables in CSS Selectors. My question is long so I created a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/FkdNSaG7

Answer (score 41):

From the [Sass Reference on "Interpolation"](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

> You can also use SassScript variables in selectors and property names using #{} interpolation syntax:

```
$gutter: 10;

.grid#{$gutter} {
    background: red;
}
```

Furthermore, the [`@each`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive) directive is not needed to make interpolation work, and as your `$gutter` only contains one value, there's no need for a loop.

If you had multiple values to create rules for, you could then use a [Sass list](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) and [`@each`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive):

```
$grid: 10, 40, 120, 240;

@each $i in $grid {
  .g#{$i}{
    width: #{$i}px;
  }
}
```

...to generate the following output:

```
.g10  { width: 10px; }
.g40  { width: 40px; }
.g120 { width: 120px; }
.g240 { width: 240px; }
```

[Here are some more examples.](https://gist.github.com/1464180).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution

```
$gutter: 10;

@each $i in $gutter {
  .g#{$i}{
     background: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: This only outputs .g10

Answer (score 0):

if it would be a vendor prefix, in my case the mixin did not compile. So I used this example

```
@mixin range-thumb()
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -14px; 
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;

input[type=range]
  &::-webkit-slider-thumb
    @include range-thumb()
  &::-moz-range-thumb
    @include range-thumb()
  &::-ms-thumb
    @include range-thumb()
```